# Java double calculate and convert to String

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, double

so I got a Problem coding in Java.

I have some doubles declared and I need to calculate with them. But I dont know who I convert the doubles to a result that can be posted in a JLabel as a String. It always says something like: cannot convert double to String. I have tried toString method but I am either doing it wrong or it just doesnt work. Any ideas for a working code?

Comment: Help us help you - share the code you have so far, the output you're getting and the output you're actually getting

Comment: Generally speaking, you're going to want to print the value to, say, 2 d.p. so look at `String.format("%.2f", yourDouble)`

Comment: @Mureinik Hey I was not able to share the code tho. I have solved it now anyways but simply using the valueOf(). But thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double)).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double val = 12.34;
        String strVal = String.valueOf(val);
        System.out.println(strVal);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
12.34
```